# Creating a PHP session from jQuery script that's on a different URL?

Tags: php, jquery

Here's my setup:

I have a jQuery/ajax script to login a user. This script is hosted on URL A and POSTs the data to URL B where a PHP page validates the information. It looks something like this:

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: 'http://URLB',
  data: $(e.target).serialize(),
  dataType: "text",
  error: function(jqXHR,textStatus,errorThrown) {
    // 
  },
  success: function(xml) {
    // I get a successul return that includes the PHP Session ID and other info         
  }
});
```

When I run the script from URL A, the I get a successful response from the PHP page on URL B signalling the user is now logged in. On the backend, URL B started a PHP Session.

The problem is that when I visit URL B, it's like the user was never logged in and the PHP Session never started.

Does anyone know why the Session isn't active when I visit URL B? When I do the POST, I get a PHP Session ID and everything so I don't understand what I'm missing.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: I believe a session contains the domain it was created on along with other unique information to secure the session. Otherwise anyone could create a session and gain access to your website. Why are you attempting to log into one website from another?

Comment: The user creates a new account from the corporate website and then they get transferred to the app... where I don't want them to have to re-login. Make sense?

Comment: @Stefan - It seems you are correct so I'm going to have to find another workaround. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: It makes sense. But I think users expect to have to log into a new website so I don't think UX is an issue you need to worry about.